# Error: Cannot find module "socket.io-client/package" when building with webpack

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webpack

Trying to build simple chat server application with socket.io, and assemble it to one js file with webpack. App works well without webpack assembling. But when I try to assemble all my scripts with webpack, it throws error:

```
Error: Cannot find module "socket.io-client/package"
```

I have find the place in socket.io library where this require method calls. Its 11 line in socket.io/lib/index.js file.

```
var clientVersion = require('socket.io-client/package').version;
```

As I undestand socket.io requires package.json of it`s dependency socket.io-client library. I tried to add a json loader but it did not help. What to do next I don't know.

main.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var listener = io(9999);
...
```

webpack.config

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: './temp',
        filename: 'chat-server.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/json-loader). Install it.

I think you'll also need to tell webpack to look for json files. You can do that with the [`resolve.extensions`](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#resolveextensions) option. Just include `'.json'` there.

A better solution I would suggest is to use a [webpack replace plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins) and replace that string with the actual version. Something like this:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin('require(\'socket.io-client/package\').version', require('socket.io-client/package').version)
```

Comment: Thanks, Louy, it helps!