# socket.io angular-cli cannot resolve 'socket.io-client/package'

Tags: angular, socket.io, angular-cli

I am working on a project that is using 1.0 of angular-cli and I am trying to include socket.io into that project. However, I am faced with the following errors and I am not sure how to get around them.

### Error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'socket.io-client/package'

There is a warning before this error is shown referring to an unexpected token from a socket.io file namely socket.io.js.map. When I look at this file it appears to be a JSON file.

### Warning for socket.io.js.map

> Module parse failed: D:\madlink-test-app\madlink-dongle-app-two\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist\socket.io.js.map Unexpected token (1:10)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372346/error-cannot-find-module-socket-io-client-package-when-building-with-webpack) it seems that I need json-loader, but from what I can tell this is included automatically when using angular-cli. Any advice that is offered for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

angular-cli version: 1.0.0

### tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: like-wise, having the same issue over here. hopefully this gets bumped

Comment: I did temporarily fix this by replacing the "require('socket.io-client/package').version" with a hard-coded value. However, that is not a long term solution just a band-aid.

Comment: actually, I found a way around. what I did that is similar to what you did was add `.json` to `package`, as it simply failed to find the file. The real fix was to use `socket.io-client` instead of `socket.io` in the imports, and it just worked. I opened an issue in `angular-cli`'s github, so lets see what they'll do with the issue here. But for now, importing `socket.io-client` does the job.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for opening an issue and for finding an alternate temporary solution.

Comment: Do you have a link to the issue you opened?

Comment: [YUP, INDEED I DO](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6168)